# Make value of a measure "static" in chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a measure that is returning the average daily count that works great. I want to use this daily count value as a "Static Value" on an area chart to easily visualize when daily volume falls below expected. Because the area chart is using NotificationDate on the X-axis, I believe the measure is calculating in-real time on that date, not actual "average" of all days currently filtered on. I have provided visuals below of what's happening vs. expectation. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Avg Daily Alerts = 
VAR tbl =
    SUMMARIZE(
        dimAlert,
        dimAlert[NotificationDate],
        "Count", COUNTROWS(dimAlert)
    )
RETURN
    AVERAGEX(tbl, [Count])
```

**Actual**
[Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgrVn.png)

**Expected:**
[Expected Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta5W3.png)

Comment: Did you checked the option of adding "Average line" in the chart? It's a default feature for Line chart.

Comment: I posted an answer below that achieved the desired result. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there was an option under "Add More Analysis to this Visual" that allowed me to use a field value as a constant line for the visual. This achieved the desired result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TjMQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remove any filters on the date table to do that. There's one kind of implied by the visual you're using, and you need to remove that. Something like

```
Avg Daily Alerts = 
VAR tbl =
    SUMMARIZE(
        dimAlert,
        dimAlert[NotificationDate],
        "Count", COUNTROWS(dimAlert)
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(tbl, [Count]), ALL('DimDate'[Date]) )
```